# Would it be faster to put all queries at the start of the php file?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am creating a website with content generated by php and mysql. All over the page, you will see stuff like comments, user profile information, announcements, etc that require the use of mysql queries and php.

As you can see there will be lots of mysql queries and row fetching being done throughout the whole page.

1. Would it be faster if I call all queries, fetch all rows and put them into arrays at the start of the php file? Or would it be faster if I just dispersed them throughout the document? e.g. Put the comment queries, comment row fetches and comment array definitions where the comment section is.
2. If I placed all the queries at the start of the document, would it be faster to combine all the queries into one huge query? I'm worried about the memory usage here.
3. After defining arrays using values fetched from mysql queries, I usually free the results of the query. Is this beneficial or just a waste of time?

Comment: You should probably rethink your architecture and consider implementing an MVC pattern or some other pattern where you can separate the queries from the page display logic.

Comment: Use a profiler (xdebug + kcachegrind) to find out. Depends on the database. But if you issue the queries, then do something different in your PHP script before fetching the results, the database could use that bit of time to prepare the result sets. Might be possible. But beware that running many concurrent queries consumes more memory, doesn't speed up the DB, so might be counterproductive for efficiency.

Comment: So you suggest combining all the queries into a huge query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You should separate application logic from presentational code. So in this sense, yes, you should perform the queries required to build a page before actually rendering the page. It is not 'faster', but it makes your application easier to understand, maintain and extend.

2) It is always worth performing as few queries as possible, so long as your results sets don't start needing large amounts of post-processing by PHP to be usable by the application.

3) It's a waste of time.

Comment: Well I do process the data obtained from the database (calculate the time difference, htmlentities, nl2br). Would it then be better to separate the queries?

Comment: You can often do things like calculate time differences within the queries themselves (see the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)). Formatting functions like `nl2br` can be left to the presentational code. The post-processing I was referring to would be more akin to, for example, remapping results arrays. The best rule of thumb is the fewer queries the better!

Answer (score -3):

What I normally do to make php run faster;

Put all variables at the top, use if, elseif etc, and else, then order your queries in the order you think which will be most popular. That way if the query is unlikely then it will not execute as it is further down the elseif list.

I would free the result, especially when checking if a variable already exists or not in the db.

Some more tips...

Use session_write_close where possible.

Place all arrays at top of page.

Sometimes using flush() can help, you would have to try it out.

Comment: old members get all technical